# Есть ли стандартные функции для чтения конфигурационных файлов?

Tags: php

такого вида:

```
app1.url = http://site.com
app1.username = user
app1.passsword = pass

app2.url = http://site2.com
app2.username = user2
app2.passsword = pass2
```

Хм... у ini файлов немного другая структура. 
пример:

```
[app1] 
url = http://site.com 
username = user 
password = pass

[app2] 
url = http://site2.com 
username = user2 
password = pass2
```

Comment: Можно писать конфиги в таком виде и не заморачиваться:  

    $app1= Array(
        "url" => "http://site.com",
        "username" => "user",
        "passsword" => "pass"
    )

Но если Вы встали на путь файлов конфигураций, то лучше воспользоваться стандартами, например [INI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ini), который все знают и любят и полно [парсеров на PHP](https://www.google.ru/search?q=php+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80+ini&oq=php+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80+ini&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5808j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно есть: [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-ini-file.php)

> `parse_ini_file` — Обрабатывает конфигурационный файл

Comment: обратите внимание на второй параметр этой функции